# How to Autoload & Display Images in View (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am a newbie to codeigniter framework. I have created a PHP slider that load images automatically, it works fine in PHP only. Now I used codeigniter, the PHP code does not work well, just can't read the images in a folder.

PHP code:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="phpSlider">
        <?php $dir_handle='./slider/images/'; 
            foreach(array_diff(scandir($dir_handle), array( '.', '..')) as $file) { 
                echo '<img src="./slider/images/'.$file. '" />'; 
            } 
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

the code works fine without codeigniter. It reads all images in a specific folder "images" under "slider" folder. And the code when run on browser looks like below:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider" class="phpSlider">
        <img src="slider/images/banner1.jpg">
        <img src="slider/images/banner2.jpg">
        <img src="slider/images/banner3.jpg">
        <img src="slider/images/banner4.jpg">
        <img src="slider/images/banner5.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what does it do in Codeigniter that is different? I see that your links in the PHP of your view is different to the HTML you have shown.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw just ignore the html code above. I just want to accomplish in codeigniter to load images in a specific folder and then display in view.

Comment: Well if I am to ignore the code in your question, then my answer would be  to write the correct code that works. Your issue will be with the file paths.

Comment: @TimBrownlaw, yeah I'm messing up with my file path. I'll figure it out. btw thanks Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the folder path to absolute URL solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is looking like a path issue. Please use base_url() with img src. where base_url() is your project directory url where your index.php file exist.

```html
echo '<img src="'.base_url().'path/to/images/'.$file. '" />';
```

Comment: i have some trouble loading images with your suggestion above. So far no error, but the images won't load. @ShoaibRehan

Comment: did you setup your base_url in application/config/config.php file