# image not displaying in Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Controller has `index()` method and `display()` method.

Method `index` displays the image. and this method called `display()` doesn't display the images.

Both methods are in same controller.

Both methods are calling the same view file called

`$this->load->view('home/portfolio2');`

.
 `index()` method is displaying the image but `display()` method not displaying the image.

index method code is

```
public function index() { //$this->load->view('images/homeimage'); //home image. 
 $this->load->view('home/portfolio2'); 
 $this->load->view('home/header'); 
 $this->load->view('home/viewcategory');
 $result['msg'] = $this->W_model->latestupdates(); 
 $result['title'] = 'latest updated';
 if($result['msg'] == NULL) {
   echo "check for albums in DB"; 
 }else{
   $this->load->view('home/latestsongsupdated', $result);
 }
$this->load->view('home/footer');
}
```

display method code is

```
Public function displayalbums($albums, $lang){ 
 $result['title'] = $lang; 
 $result['msg'] = $this->W_model->displayalbum($albums); 
 if($result['msg'] == NULL) { ?> 
   <h3 style = "margin-left: 20px;">
     <?php echo "Songs will be updated soon, Please check for other songs"; ?> 
   </h3> <?php 
 } else{
   $this->load->view('home/portfolio2');
   $this->load->view('home/viewcategory');
   $this->load->view('home/albums', $result); 
 }
}
```

Any advise, help will be more appreciated.

Comment: pls show code, without it can not help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159902/how-to-autoload-display-images-in-view-codeigniter

Comment: You should post both the function.

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code.

Comment: From your functions, I can say that it has nothing to do with controller functions. You are using two different views `home/latestsongsupdated` in `index()` and `home/albums` view in `displayalbums()`

Can you post the image tag with which you are trying to show the image ?

Comment: <img src="assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg" alt="worship to Lord"> when i used base_url() in src then it is showing nothing, just thumbnail.

Comment: it has nothing to do with home/latestsongsupdated and home/albums. i am using home/portfolio for displaying the image in both methods. in index() image is displaying but not in display()

Comment: @raviraj123456 I can not see any changes in the code. Did you post the img tag ?

Comment: <img src="assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg" alt="worship to Lord">yes i posted it in comment section. @Himanshu Upadhyay

Comment: @raviraj123456 can you use the full URL like this: 'http://example.com/assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg' in src ?

Comment: Thank you so much @HimanshuUpadhyay. its working now after using the whole url in src like <img src="http://localhost/worship/assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg" alt="worship to Lord">

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for image src is:

```
<?php echo base_url('assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg'); ?>
```

If that does not work `echo base_url()` somewhere. It should point to `localhost/worship` if your entire CI is in an htdocs or HTML subfolder that's called `workshop`. If it doesn't then you should edit your `base_url` correctly in the config as `http://localhost/workship`.

You can also use the image helper to generate the image tag (load HTML helper):

```
<?php echo img('assets/images/glow_in_worship_by_riyovincent-d571aon.jpg'); ?>
```

Note: this method also requires the `base_url` to be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

@raviraj123456 
Use the full URL like this: 'http://www.example.com/assets/images/…; in src of the img tag and it will work.